# Formatting a return value from a serial device

Tags: python, pyserial

I am reading a value from a device over serial, and the return value has the format:

[Theoretical position in mm, Encoder position in mm], for example, b'\r#-0.001504,-0.001516\n'

I would like to format this return value and save the second value into an array. Does anyone have an idea how I might do this? Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Thanks.

New edit: This is my code and output. At this point I only need to extract the float value from this string.

```
    ser.write(b'1POS?\r') #command to query position
    pos = ser.readline() #read the position
    pos_str = str(pos)
    pos_splt = pos_str.split(",") 
    enc_pos = pos_splt[1]
    print(enc_pos)
```

Output: "-0.028970\n'"

Comment: Yes, I have an idea. But first, what have you tried?

Comment: You can use `.split("separator")` to split your string

Comment: A combination of `strip`, `split`, and `float` seems like it'd do most of the job.

Comment: You should show the code you have tries yet to get some help.

Comment: I noticed that you commented out `print(pos)`. What happens if you restore that line after you read from the serial port?

Comment: @quamrana if it print pos, it prints 6 every time, which is an error code from my device. It's not a valid value.

Comment: It sounds like you also need some code to handle this error code. But, unless you start getting valid data, you won't be able to validate your code that processes position data.

Comment: @quamrana I have succeeded in getting the string that I want from the device. I now just need to extract the float value from that string. This float value will be different every time my loop iterates, so I can't just search for the value itself.

Comment: I have figured out how to remove the n' from the string, but for some reason when I use str.replace() I can't get the \ character to go away

Comment: Your mistake now is: `pos_str = str(pos)`. See my new answer,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, sorry, I've just realised what your:
`error "a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'"`
means.

Its because what you are trying to split is a bytes array, which, although it has a `split()` method, its requires a bytes array as the parameter.

Try this now:

```py
pos = b'\r#-0.001504,-0.001516\n'   # Sample data from serial port

pos_splt = pos.strip().split(b",")  # the param b"," is the bytes version of ","
enc_pos = pos_splt[1]
print(float(enc_pos))
```

Output

```
-0.001516
```