# Formatting string from serial device

Tags: python, arduino, serial-port

I know I asked a similar question before ([Formatting a return value from a serial device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67570891/formatting-a-return-value-from-a-serial-device)), but this time around my question is different. I am reading a value from an Arduino, that looks something like this:

value = b'446.45 mV\r\n'

What I need from this, is simply 446.45. My code below works to extract this value, but every once and a while it will decide to not work. I am calling this value many times, up to 10,000 or more. It is frustrating when I get the error: "ValueError: could not convert string to float: '' " when I am on the 9000th iteration of my data collection. Does anyone know what my issue might be?

```
value = ser2.readline() # gives something like: b'446.45 mV\r\n'
val_str = str(value)
count = val_str.count('.') #count number of decimal points
if count != 1: #make sure there is only one decimal point
    val_str = val_str[:6] #keep two decimal points 
w = val_str.strip("b")
x = w.strip("mV\\r\\n")
y = float(x) # usually gives: 446.45
```

Comment: What is `value` or `val_str` when you get the ValueError? Wrap your code in a try/except so you can print it on error.

Comment: use try except and print the offending values

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because your device gives different output due to serial port or cable corruption and your program cannot translate it to float.

Unfortunately you did not provide all the data, so I could not test the solution, but this is the best I could think of.

```
my_str = b'446.45 mV\r\n'
def separate(value):
   value = value.decode("utf8") # decoding the value (it is better to use my_str.decode() instead of str(my_str))
   value = value.split('m')[0] # removing all the letter that go after m
   return float(value) # returning the separated value
separate(my_str)
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I may have found the cause. Every so often the Arduino spits out two voltage readings at once, and it looks something like this: 306.632293.96. By having two decimal places in my string, the code doesn't know how to convert to a float. So I need an error code or a solution to that.

Comment: I have edited my code to include the fix.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are sending analog Data from your Arduino to Python I highly recommend to send the raw 10-Bit (or sometimes 12-Bit) integers. This will make conversion much easier.

If you have your Arduino doing something like this:

```cpp
Serial.println(analogRead(some_port));
```

then the Arduino will send the int data in ascii-bytes.

You can then grab those by doing something like this in python:

```python
value = ser2.readline()
int_value = str(int(value))

# Here you can then calculate voltages based on that

voltage = 5/1023 * int_value
```